# Query performance problem

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm having troubles with certain query performance, i have the following 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `CustFullName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `CustPassword` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `CustEmail` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `SocialNetworkId` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `CustUID` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL,
  `CustMoney` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `LastIpAddress` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL,
  `LastLoginTime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '1900-10-10 10:10:10',
  `SmallPicURL` varchar(120) CHARACTER SET ascii DEFAULT '',
  `LargePicURL` varchar(120) CHARACTER SET ascii DEFAULT '',
  `LuckyChips` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `AccountCreationTime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '2009-11-11 11:11:11',
  `AccountStatus` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `CustLevel` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `City` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `State` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Country` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Zip` varchar(16) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL,
  `CustExp` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`CustUID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

And:

```
CREATE TABLE `mutualfriends` (
  `CustUID` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL,
  `CustUID2` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL,
  `FType` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CustUID`,`CustUID2`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

customers table contains 1M rows and mutalfriends about 50k rows.

I need the results of the following query:

```
SELECT c.CustUID, c.CustFullName, c.CustMoney, c.SmallPicURL
FROM `customers` c
WHERE c.`CustUID` = '9:2'
OR c.`CustUID` IN
(SELECT m.CustUID2 FROM mutualfriends m WHERE m.CustUID = '9:2');
OR c.`CustUID` IN
(SELECT m.CustUID FROM mutualfriends m WHERE m.CustUID2 = '9:2');
```

for some reason i don't understand, this query takes about 10 secconds to finish. 
The sub queries contains no more than 3 rows each,  if i put constants instead of:

```
(SELECT m.CustUID2 FROM mutualfriends m WHERE m.CustUID = '9:2');
```

And:

```
 (SELECT m.CustUID FROM mutualfriends m WHERE m.CustUID2 = '9:2');
```

For example:

```
 SELECT c.CustUID, c.CustFullName, c.CustMoney, c.SmallPicURL
    FROM `customers` c
    WHERE c.`CustUID` = '9:2'
    OR c.`CustUID` IN
    ('9:3','9:4','9:5');
    OR c.`CustUID` IN
    ('9:6','9:7');
```

Then The query takes a few ms to finish.
What am i doing wrong here this query shouldn't take more than a few ms...

also i may add that this part of the query:

```
(SELECT m.CustUID2 FROM mutualfriends m WHERE m.CustUID = '9:2');
(SELECT m.CustUID FROM mutualfriends m WHERE m.CustUID2 = '9:2');
```

also takes a few ms....

Answer (score 0):

There are any number of pages out on the net that will tell you how to optimize queries, but my first guess is that MySQL isn't using the index on mutualfriends because it's made of two columns.

Comment: I dont think so because this line alone takes a few ms: (SELECT m.CustUID2 FROM mutualfriends m WHERE m.CustUID = '9:2');

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html. Also a quick google search will come back with lots of starting points to handle SQL optimizations. Most rely on `EXPLAIN` though, so start there.

Regarding you query, `CustUID2` will trigger a full table scan, as its not directly indexed. Also, be careful about using sub-queries, as i have met some cases where the optimizer couldn't fully optimize the sub-query... in my case it was enough to split the query in more queries(without sub-queries).
It might also help to use `JOIN`'s as they are handled differently than sub-queries.

Answer (score 0):

Some random guesses:

```
(SELECT m.CustUID FROM mutualfriends m WHERE m.CustUID2 = '9:2');
```

...is **probably** not able to use the index (CustUID, CustUID2) efficiently. You have to check the explain plan. In case it doesn't, consider adding another uniue index (CustUID2, CustUID).

Expressions like

```
WHERE <constant>
   OR <subquery>
```

...generates a crappy plan in Oracle. Maybe this is the case for MySQL too? It can usually be resolved by working the constant expression inside the subquery somehow or rephrasing the logic a bit.

Another idea is to perform three queries and UNION them together. In case you expect a lot of rows to be returned, this option is less attractive as the sorting will kill performance.

```
select *
  from customer 
 where CustUID = '9:2'
union
select *
  from customer
 where CustUID in(select m.CustUID from mutualfriends m where m.CustUID2 = '9:2')
union
select *
  from customer
 where CustUID in(select m.CustUID2 from mutualfriends m where m.CustUID = '9:2')
```